# Can I install Ubuntu on windows 7 without affecting the recovery facility of windows 7?

Tags: dual-boot

I have windows 7 homebasic and now i want o install ubuntu 14.04 over it, i want to keep both (dual boot) . Windows 7 has recovery facility , will ubuntu installation affect the recovery of windows 7 or not ?
  How can i do it ?

Comment: you can installl ubuntu over win 7 with no problem, but be sure the recovery partation is untouched..

Comment: And ALWAYS make a BACKUP of your important files.

Answer (score 0):

If you just follow the guided installation "install alongside Windows 7" it should work fine and with no problems; if you decide to manually edit your pc's partitions, make sure to leave the recovery partition as is, as rajan suggested

Comment: Ok , I'll follow the installation-guide !! Anyways , Thanks